# ErrorException copy(C:\laragon\www\himochibear\database/seeders/IndoRegionDistrictSeeder.php): failed to open stream: No such file directory

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laragon

[image]

ErrorException
copy(C:\laragon\www\himochibear\database/seeders/IndoRegionDistrictSeeder.php): failed to open stream: No such file directory

> `public function copy ($path, $target) { return copy($path, $target); }`

> i found error in `php artisan db:seed --class=IndoRegionSeeder`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. composer require azishapidin/indoregion
2. php artisan indoregion:publish
3. Create a folder "seeders" in the database folder. Later there will be 2 folders visible; seeds & seeders (the new folder).
4. composer dump-autoload
5. Copy the files that are in the seeders to seeds
6. php artisan db:seed --class=IndoRegionSeeder
7. If there is an error in number 5 enter one by one :

   php artisan db:seed --class=IndoRegionProvinceSeeder

   php artisan db:seed --class=IndoRegionRegencySeeder

   php artisan db:seed --class=IndoRegionDistrictSeeder

   php artisan db:seed --class=IndoRegionVillageSeeder